# How to view full results for a Facebook Messenger poll

Tags: facebook-messenger

I created a poll in a Messenger chat group and I need to see who voted for the roles they are able to do, but I can only see two avatars and a +2 more.

Is there any way to see all the votes?

I'm using Windows 10, Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

I found I could get who voted for each option by opening the poll in the iPhone app. I assume that also works on Android.

This provides one way for some peole to see "who voted for the roles"

However, it won't work for users who only have access to a browser.

Comment: Facebook should get the -1 for not providing the functionality in the browser ;-)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Man, FB is going lazy about this, especially now on RAD learning. This function is now an essential.

Comment: Think it's for privacy. Slightly harder to screenshot on mobile whereas on browser it could be automated.